# Why does `sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet` convert dates to UTC when exported from SAP Fiori launchpad, even though I set the `utc: false`?

Tags: excel, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, sap-basis

I am using `sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet` to export some data to Excel. My problem is that the date field values are always converted to UTC. I don't have this problem on my local SAP Web IDE. But when I try exporting from the launchpad, dates values are converted to UTC.

Here is my `createColumnConfig` code that I copied from https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet

```js
aCols.push({
  label: "Start Date",
  property: "StartDate",
  type: EdmType.DateTime,
  utc: false
});
```

Here is what exported excel looks like on web ide:

[image]

Here is what exported excel looks like on launchpad:

[image]

Why is it not working on SAP Fiori launchpad?

Comment: With which SAPUI5 version is the app running?

Comment: If you go to your user settings within the launchpad (click your avatar and select "Settings"), and navigate to "Language & Region", what is the Time Zone setting there?

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann SAPUI5 version is 1.65.7 (20190826-1301).  Under settings->languange&region there is no timezone setting. Just language, date format and time format.

Comment: So the FLP is served from an on-premise ABAP system, and not from the cloud (cFLP), right? AFAIK, the FLP on legacy systems incorporates user settings incl. time zone from the ABAP system.

Comment: Also please upgrade the SAPUI5 version in your system. Version [1.65 is **out of maintenance**!](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html)

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann thank you very much for your answer, I've changed timezone setting for user on on-prem system but dates are still converted to UTC.

Comment: Could you try running the app in FLP with the latest stable SAPUI5 version? That would be currently 1.105.0. Other **currently maintained versions** are listed here: https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html